# Choppy Flash Video Playback

Tags: flash, playback

I am having major choppy flash video playback issues with Ubuntu 11.04. The issue only occurs while playing flash video. It works fine in regular video playback (divx/xvid).

I have and have tried the following:

- ATI Radeon 4200 (integrated graphics)
- Using Latest ATI/AMD Proprietary Driver FGLRX
- Ran Update Manager
- AMD X4 630 CPU
- Played flash video in 360 quality
- Latest version of 64-bit flash beta installed
- Flash-Aid installed on Firefox
- Tried in both Firefox and Chrome, but still laggy.
- Attempted to make a new user account, and tried it on there, but still doesn't work.

TIA!

Comment: it's flash, what did you expect?!

Comment: @AsianXL - is it just youtube flash you have issues with?  Have you tried youtube html5 videos ?

Comment: fossfreedom - Thanks for the prompt response. I am actually not having any video playback issues on Youtube, rather I am having problems playing flash video on other video sites.

Comment: I guess I would say there is a reason for get-flash-video.

Comment: get-flash-video doesn't work on the video site that I am watching from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling hardware acceleration in flash. Worked for some YouTube videos for me on my ATI HD3000 series graphics card. HTML5 is the way to go though

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that on other videos. It didn't appear to work on the site that I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Try using gnash instead of Flashplayer. To install gnash  `sudo apt-get install gnash` . I have used it for over a year and gnash seems to work better than flash.

If you feel better uninstalling flash then installing gnash you can do this by opening terminal

sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-nonfree flashplugin-installer gnash gnash-common mozilla-plugin-gnash swfdec-mozilla

`sudo rm -f /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

`sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so`

`sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so`

`sudo rm -f /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/npwrapper*flash*so`

`rm -f ~/.mozilla/plugins/*flash*so`

`sudo apt-get install gnash`

Comment: Is entering that code all I need to do? Any other settings I need to tinker with?

Comment: thats all you need to do gnash will play flash sites instead of flash player

Comment: Do I need to uninstall flash too? just incase it interferes?

Comment: no sir you shouldn't need to uninstall flash