# Video not playing, only freeze-frame, jump possible, gstreamer issue?

Tags: video, totem, gstreamer

Since nearly one week I'm not able to play videos properly (Ubuntu 16.04). The first frame is shown, but only this as a freeze frame. Jumping to a different position is possible, but same result, no audio playback at all.

First I guess it was only in HTML5 online Videos, in Chromium and Firefox. Checked the codecs and tried new profile, no success. Checked older kernels no success either. [Online html5 check](https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html) does not find anything strange. Updated Intel graphics driver with the Intel tool, no change at all.

Today I realized it is the same behavior with offline videos (tested: `*.mp4`, `*.webm`, `*.ogv`). Totem Player and banshee, same issues. But VLC working as expected. Tried to reinstall gstreamer but with no success.

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73071/online-video-playback-in-all-browsers-halting-and-unwatchable) solution as well, but no success.

Can someone push me in the right direction to solve the annoying issue? Any other information needed?

P.S.: Only thing which comes to my mind, I calibrated my monitor with `displaycal_3.3.5.0-1_amd64` (downloaded new deb package and install manually).

Comment: Since VLC is working, would it be worth trying a different codec library? like installing `gstreamer-ffmpeg` or `gstreamer-libav` and seeing if those improve playback?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is installed, reinstallation with no sucess. `gstreamer-ffmpeg` was tested as well, I will check `gstreamer-libav` and give feedback later today.

Comment: I will check `libgstreamer0.10-0` and `libgstreamer1.0-0` as well.

Comment: `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` and  `gstreamer1.0-libav` were already installed, no success.

Comment: Installed `gstreamer1.0-nice`, no change.

Comment: Both `libgstreamer0.10-0` and `libgstreamer1.0-0` were already installed. Any other hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a clean system (Ubuntu 17.10) and gstreamer works as expected. (For sure I installed the `ubuntu-restricted-extras`).

So a clean new system was the solution for me.